# mod_rewrite using nonexistent folder as query variable

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to get the following working (think bitly.com/links):

```
http://example.com/abc123
```

Where the URL needs to be adjusted to:

```
http://example.com/index.php?item_id=abc123
```

Note: abc123 is dynamic and can be anything. I keep getting 404 errors. Index.php exists and is working properly.

I've searched and tried the following without success:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?item_id=$1 [L]
```

.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?item_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The first rule doesn't make sense (It matches 0 or more ^'s or /'s from the beginning of the string). When you use the second rule, and use a tool like wget or curl to request the url and inspect the HTTP headers that are returned, is there a 302 response? What is the url you are being redirected to (Location header)?

Comment: It’s never getting to the page. That’s what’s driving me crazy.

Comment: I'll repeat my advice: as next step in my analysis I would use a tool like wget or curl to request the original url, inspect the headers and see what it's being redirected to in the Location header (assuming there is a 302 status response).

Comment: Is rewrite enable? Do you have `RewriteEngine On`?

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work:
Put this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^index/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?item_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# rule to add `.php` extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

now search example.com/abc123